# Similar to Computing the Exact Offset in CGAL, can I compute the "exact buffer" of a polyline?

Tags: c++, computational-geometry, cgal

Is there any already built and ready to use C++ algorithms out there similar to CGAL's offset_2 function but instead of computing the Minkowski sum of a circle and a polygon, the Minkowski sum of a circle and a polyline is computed (i.e., the buffer of the polyline)?

In application this is what I would like to do:

1. Input a polyline with n vertices: ([x_0,y_0],[x_1,y_1],...,[x_n-1,y_n-1])
2. Find the exact buffer of this polyline (output is a polygon that may have holes)
3. Extract each individual conic-arc to test for intersections with other lines I have.
4. display this buffered polyline

Thanks

EDIT: Possible Solution

Could I just generate a circle of radius r at each vertex and a rectangle with width of 2r along each line segment, and then take the union of these?

If I understand the CGAL documentation correctly, I can get an exact solution (i.e., something made up of conic arc), correct? If so, some guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know this package, but would turning a polyline ABCDE into a flat polygon ABCDEDCB help?

Comment: @MarcGlisse Are polygons of that type allowed? I am very new to CGAL, but would that also be computationally inefficient?

Comment: @MarcGlisse I did what you suggested but it returns the following error: `CGAL ERROR: precondition violation!`, followed by `Expr: pgn.is.simple()`. So it seems that I can not use flat polygons as they are not simple.

Comment: @MarcGlisse I posted a solution to this question, a second opinion would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for everything, you seem to always comment on my questions and help out the most!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, following from my suggested solution, the Minkowski sum of a polyline and a circle of radius `r` is the union of circles or radius `r` at each vertex and rectangles of width `r` about each line segment.

Following this, I used the [Boolean Set-Operations on General Polygons](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Boolean_set_operations_2/index.html#bso_secbso_gen)
and the example therein, which conveniently takes the union of circles of rectangles. The key feature of this was the fact that the  `GeneralPolygon_2` concept was used, which allows me to get an exact solution in the form of linear functions and circular arcs.

Here is a snippet of my code (note that my inputted polyline uses complex coordinates):

```
Polygon_set_2 S;
// Generate a Circle for each Vertex
for (int i=0; i<complexPolygon.size(); ++i){
    S.join(construct_polygon(Circle_2(Point_2(real(complexPolygon[i]), imag(complexPolygon[i])),1)));
}
// Generate a Rectangle for Each Ordered Pair of Vertices
for (int i=0; i<complexPolygon.size()-1; ++i){
    complex<double> P1, P2, P12, R1, R2, R3, R4;
    P1 = complexPolygon[i];
    P2 = complexPolygon[i+1];
    P12 = P2-P1;
    R1 = P1 - complex<double>(0,w)*P12/abs(P12);
    R4 = P1 + complex<double>(0,w)*P12/abs(P12);
    R2 = R1 + P12;
    R3 = R4 +P12;

    S.join(construct_polygon(Point_2(real(R1), imag(R1)), Point_2(real(R2), imag(R2)),
                             Point_2(real(R3), imag(R3)), Point_2(real(R4), imag(R4))));
}
fstream minkFile;
minkFile.open("mink.txt",ios::out);//open in write mode
if(minkFile.is_open()){
    list<Polygon_with_holes_2> res;
    S.polygons_with_holes (std::back_inserter (res));
    copy (res.begin(), res.end(),
    ostream_iterator<Polygon_with_holes_2>(minkFile, "\n"));
    cout << endl;
}
```